# GPS Tracklog from iPhone

Tags: iphone, gps

When bushwalking I use my Garmin GPS to record tracklogs, which I can later download.

I was wondering if the iPhone5 has a similar capability. This could be handy when travelling.

I have searched the web and the App Store. There seem to be many apps which will let you track someone else and display their location, but I have no desire to do this. I would like to be able just to log the location of my phone. There seem to be a couple of apps which seem to be geared at fitness and map display.

I don't need (or want) a Map display on the iPhone (because most of the places I would use it there is little or no mobile coverage).
In particular I want to be able to record locations in remote areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Motion-X GPS](http://gps.motionx.com) [comes in free & paid versions]

Can track using only GPS, if you have data roaming off or are outside signal reception areas.

You can pre-load maps at many zoom levels if you wish, for when know you will not be getting a data signal on your trip.

Comment: Thanks to both respondents. Both apps looked OK; I elected to try Motion-X as it seems to be updated recently. No free version, but the $1.29 is not an issue. I gave it its first test and the result looks good.

Comment: Glad it's looking promising. Wasn't aware they'd stopped the free version, I started on that then bought the full version.

Answer (score 1):

I use "GPS Kit" for this. It lets you record the movement of your iPhone for as long you want, and save them for later viewing. It even lets you broadcast your track so that others can view it as you move, if you want to do that for some reason. You can also cache offline maps, if you do want to be able to see where you are in remote locations. It doesn't need the maps to function though. It tracks your GPS coordinates the entire time, you just can't see where you are without data, but it sounds like that's okay with you.